# Loopback: Auto-discover database structures and auto-generate relations between tables

Tags: postgresql, strongloop, loopback, autodiscovery, apiconnect

We are using Loopback as a standard RESTFul API.

I have a script that is used to auto-generate the model data based off of discovery of the database tables/structures.

I can generate the schema data for each table, but I don't know how to generate the relations property data for each table, which is important.

For example, this data from a `servers/models/model-x.json` model schema:

```
 "validations": [],
  "relations": {    <<<<  definitely need this property to be filled
    "members": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "memberId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
```

**so my question is** - is it possible to generate this relations data from the tables and the foreign keys in tables? Or is this data too complex to autogenerate?

Answer (score 1):

While discovering the schema you set `associations: true`.

A full code to go through all your database tables and generate the models: [Strongloop discovery model still empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630182/strongloop-discovery-model-still-empty)